# How to include and send image in whats app message using chat api

Tags: image, whatsapp

My requirement is to send image as a whats app message, how can i achieve it, below is my code and i'm using chat api.

```
        message = message.Replace("#", "\n");

        message = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/3/33/NatureCover2001.jpg";

        string param = "phone=91" + phonenumber + "&body=" + message + "&filename=cover.jpg";

        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(param);

        HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://eu9.chat-api.com/instance7102/message?token=i8ra4a0zlfxwh90b");

        WebReq.Method = "POST";
        WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        Stream PostData = WebReq.GetRequestStream();
        PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        PostData.Close();

        HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();

        Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);
        string response = _Answer.ReadToEnd();

        return response;
```

Comment: And how is your code failing? Are you getting errors, crashes, freezes, unexpected behavior or something else?

Comment: i didn't get any errors but the path that i have given for image is visible  as message text

Comment: is there any way to give the message type as "Image"?